Fetching an account declared in `declare_program!` using anchor_client
If I have my program idl imported using declare_program! how can I fetch and parse an on-chain account using it?

Figured it out. We can do:
declare_program!(my_program);
use my_program::{ID, accounts::MyAccount};

let cl = Client::new_with_options(
    cluster,
    fee_payer,
    CommitmentConfig::confirmed(),
);
let p = cl.program(ID).unwrap();
let acc_state: MyAccount = p.account(<Pubkey pointing to the account>).await?;

